# Excel formulas do not update after SAS export with Excel libname engine

Tags: excel-formula, sas, export

I am using the excel libname engine in SAS to update a workbook. In this workbook there are formulas that point to the range exported from SAS. After the export, the formulas will not update anymore unless a user enters the cell and hits Enter.
**The calculation is definitely set to Automatic**, changing it on/off does not update the formulas.
A similar question has been addressed here without any usefull answers: [excel formula not updating after sas export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642178/excel-formula-not-updating-after-sas-export).

Here is my example: `export_sheet` is the worksheet I export to, it contains the named range `rng_export_sheet`, `formula_sheet` contains formulas pointing to `export_sheet`. `sas_table` contains the information to be exported:

```
Libname XLWBK EXCEL "C:\Workbook.xlsm" SCAN_TEXT=NO;

*delete all information in the target worksheet;
proc datasets lib = XLWBK nolist; 
    delete "export_sheet$"n;     
quit;

*clear the named range so that the engine can overwrite;
proc datasets lib = XLWBK nolist; 
    delete rng_export_sheet;     
quit;

*export the data;
DATA XLWBK.rng_export_sheet;
    SET sas_table;
RUN; 

Libname XLOUT CLEAR;
```

I tried launching a macro in the workbook after the export using .Calculate on each cell containing a formula but it did not activate the formulas.

Comment: It seems the only way to programmatically solve this is by using `Application.CalculateFull` as mentioned [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/318115-enablecalculation.html). For the time being I will include this in all my workbooks that are updated this way.

Comment: Sounds like the answer to me!  If you self-answer, I'll close the other one in favor of this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Launching `Application.CalculateFull` in the target workbook seems to correct the issue, as mentioned [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/318115-enablecalculation.html).